# Eclipse Platform SDK no longer supported?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, target-platform

Since the newest Eclipse Version (2023-12) Eclipse Platform SDK seems to be no longer available. More precisely, adding content to a target platform like here: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html#example-for-adding-content-to-the-target-platform
is no longer possible. Is Eclipse Platform SDK now deprecated and if so, whats an alternative?
thank you in advance!

Comment: I used "Eclipse Project SDK" (org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group) instead. All the code is still there, just the features that have changed.